# Equal spacing between equations using align or gather

Tags: spacing, amsmath, baseline, gather

Is there an option for equal spacing between equations with and without fractions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{section}{title}
text
    \begin{gather}
    a + b + \frac{1}{2} = 1 \\
    a + b + \frac{1}{2} = 1 \\
    a + b + c = 1 \\
    a + b + c = 1
    \end{gather}
\end{section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if that is a representative example you could use `\tfrac` instead of `\frac` rather than increase the spacing

Comment: You should use `\section{Title}` instead of `\begin{section}...\end{section}`

Comment: The spacing between the formulas look even to me. Do you want even spacing between the formula numbers? That is, more space between (2) and (3), and even more space between (3) and (4). Wouldn't that give uneven spacing between the formulas?

Comment: @MadyYuvi Is there a specific reason to avoid `\begin{section}`?  The only difference I know of is it adds its own grouping, which may not be a bad thing.  And my (very limited) understanding is if that were the default, then tagging a pdf would be a slightly easier task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `\tfrac` so it fits or you could spread the equations by increasing `\jot`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{section}{title}
text
    \begin{gather}
    a + b + \frac{1}{2} = 1 \\
    a + b + \frac{1}{2} = 1 \\
    a + b + c = 1 \\
    a + b + c = 1
    \end{gather}
text
    \begin{gather}
    a + b + \tfrac{1}{2} = 1 \\
    a + b + \tfrac{1}{2} = 1 \\
    a + b + c = 1 \\
    a + b + c = 1
    \end{gather}
text
\setlength\jot{12pt}
    \begin{gather}
    a + b + \frac{1}{2} = 1 \\
    a + b + \frac{1}{2} = 1 \\
    a + b + c = 1 \\
    a + b + c = 1
    \end{gather}
\end{section}
\end{document}
```